# Make "widget" for SVG-group in D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am using D3 to manipulate an SVG, that contains several "widgets" that have behavior and can be controlled eg via events. For instance I have a spinning fan. It should be possible to turn on and off the fan. I have been able to build that in D3, but not in an elegant way, and with all the code being global. What I want to end up with is something as below:

Creation of "widget", as known from jQuery:

```
d3.select('svg').append('g').attr('id', 'myFan').fan();
```

And then I would like to turn on and off with smth like the following, also as known from jQuery:

```
d3.select('#myFan').fan('start')
d3.select('#myFan').fan('stop')
```

Is it possible to achieve this in D3, ie to create such a "widget"?

Is there generally a different approach to such a problem, when using D3?

### My current unelegant solution with global code:

Robert asked for this. Code at Codepen: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVbLYX).

**Javascript**

```
var fan = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 200)
  .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'fan')
    .attr('id', 'myFan')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(75,75)')

// Static, background disc
fan.append('circle')
    .attr('cx',0)
    .attr('cy',0)
    .attr('r',60)

// Dynamic, rotating path
var blade = fan.append('path')
    .attr('d', 'M 0 0 L -30 15 L -60 0 Z L 30 -15 L 60 0 Z ')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50,50)')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(90)');

// Static, hub
fan.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 0)
  .attr('cy', 0)
  .attr('r', 10)

var rotation = 0; // degrees
var speed = 10; // degree per call
function rotate() {
  rotation = (rotation + speed) % 360;
  blade.attr('transform', 'rotate('+rotation+')')
}

setInterval(rotate, 100);

function stop() { speed = 0; }
function start() { speed = 10; }

var ctrlPanel = d3.select('body').append('div');

ctrlPanel.append('button').text('Start').on('click', start);

ctrlPanel.append('button').text('Stop').on('click', stop);
```

**CSS**

```
path {
  fill: red;
  strok: blue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.fan circle {
  fill: lightgray;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.fan path {
  fill: darkgray;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you've currently written.

Comment: You can probably get away with editing the `d3.selection.prototype`. There's an example in the [D3 docs for datum](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) and there's a good article [example from Atlassian](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/06/extending-d3-js/).

Comment: i would use 'call' rather then editing the prototype e.g.

   d3.select('#myFan').call(fan, 'stop');

Comment: I like Tom's solution. But where is the state stored for each of the fans?

Comment: The [tutorial on reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) may help.